# What Runtime_Bad_Block mean in SMART Attributes? How critical is it?

Tags: ssd, smart, bad-sectors, bad-blocks

My SSD has the following SMART Attribute Pre-fail.

What does that mean and how critical is it?

`183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   098   001   010    Pre-fail  Always   In_the_past 60`

Comment: Without full SMART report this question is very low quality IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**183** 0xB7 SATA Downshift Error Count or **Runtime Bad Block** has the following meaning:

> Western Digital, Samsung or Seagate attribute: Either the number of
> downshifts of link speed (e.g. from 6Gbit/s to 3Gbit/s) or the total
> number of data blocks with detected, uncorrectable errors encountered
> during normal operation. Although degradation of this parameter can be
> an indicator of drive aging and/or potential electromechanical
> problems, it does not directly indicate imminent drive failure.

You can check the [SMART attributes section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology) on Wikipedia for more details.

Comment: Very vague, low quality answer based on very vague, low quality question.